# Node.js exports syntax with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Is there a way to accomplish this Node.js/CommonJS syntax with TypeScript?

```
const makeObservable = exports.makeObservable = function _makeObservable(fn: any, opts: any) {}
```

Basically as you can see, would like to declare a local variable on the same line as exporting that variable. Is it possible in strict TS?

Comment: Does this not work?: `export function foo() { return 'bar'; }`

Comment: right but would you be able to call foo() locally (in the same file)? With the syntax in the question, you can call the function locally and it's exported.

Comment: Have a try and look at the compiled JavaScript: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html. I would expect you can invoke the function within the same file.

Comment: yeah it looks like it works, but for some reason with the typescriptlang.org website, I can only convert to AMD

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%0D%0Aexport%20function%20a()%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%27outside%27)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aa()%3B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When exporting a named function, the compiled Javascript first defines the named function. You should be able to invoke the named function within the same file:

**Example:**

```
export function foo() {
    return 'bar';
}

const baz = foo();
console.log(baz);
```

compiles to CommonJS:

```
"use strict";
function foo() {
    return 'bar';
}
exports.foo = foo;
var baz = foo();
console.log(baz);  // bar
```